# Change button value using URI in React.js

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, uri, react-state

I made a few buttons that gonna change it's value into select or deselect. But I want to use URI I got from API fetch.

Here is my code:

```
const ButtonComponent = () => {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="button">
          <button onClick={() => setIsSelected(!isSelected)}>{isSelected ? "Deselect" : "Select"}</button>
          <button onClick={() => setIsSelected(!isSelected)}>{isSelected ? "Deselect" : "Select"}</button>
          <button onClick={() => setIsSelected(!isSelected)}>{isSelected ? "Deselect" : "Select"}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Where I have to put the URI so that it could be saved in the state?

Note: URI state could be array

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit, please?

Comment: I want to use API to my react, and using this button to select the data from API response. I will use the URI as identifier, but I have no idea where to put the URI. When the button clicked, URI is saved in state or localstorage. I'm sorry if I can't explain it very well, and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for but just let me know if this is ok.

```
    const ButtonComponent = () => {
      const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)
      const [uri, setUri] = useState(null)
    
      return (
        <div className="button">
              <button 
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsSelected(!isSelected)
                  setUrl('uri1')
                }}>
                {isSelected ? "Deselect" : "Select"}
              </button>
              <button 
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsSelected(!isSelected)
                  setUrl('uri2')
                }}>
                {isSelected ? "Deselect" : "Select"}
              </button>
              <button 
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsSelected(!isSelected)
                  setUrl('uri3')
                }}>
                {isSelected ? "Deselect" : "Select"}
              </button>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Do you want something like this?